# Stripe Payment Integration Php codelgniter

Tags: php

I am worked in stripe payment integration section and i integrated stripe and connected my stripe account but i doesn't know how to integrated test cards and connected stripe account

Comment: Can you share any area of your code? And as you said you already integrate the stripe, then you can directly try stripe [test cards](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards)

Comment: $payments=$stripe->paymentIntents->create([
  'description' =>$description,
  'amount' => $docAmount, 
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  ]); this is some parts of my code and iam using pho Codeignter

Comment: Wait let me share my own library for stripe with you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Stripe Custom Library](https://gist.github.com/SyedMuradAliShah/307db08b7467a05d0728be88c05c570b#file-stripe_custom_library-php) in codeingiter! You can use it your own project, all you need to set stripe `$secret_key`.

Please keep it in mind `require_once(APPPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php')`. This is the official library!

You can download it using composer! `composer require stripe/stripe-php`

**How to use it in your project?**

Call this library in your controller using `$this->load->library("stripe_custom_library");`

1. Add customer using `add_customer` function
2. Add card to customer using `add_card`
3. Now hold charge for a customer `hold_charge`
4. Once charge is hold, you can capture now using `capture_transaction`
5. In case you want to remove hold you can use `hold_remove`

There are some more methods as well, but in case you want to use them you can do it like if you need want to know whats is in IPN, you can use webhook, you can comment me if you have any issue with using this library.